# Resign first responder after touch on contentview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

Here's my setup:
I have a view containing a small view at the bottom of the screen, which contains a text field. I have added some logic to move the whole view (including the small one) up as soon as the textbox is selected, and down as soon as the textbox disappears.

I have also added a gesturerecognizer to the whole thing, to resign first responder once the user taps somewhere else.

Afterwards, I added a ContentView to all of this, which in turn references a tableviewcontroller. It looks fine: a tableview in the back, the text field in its view at the bottom, once I tap the textfield everything is moved up and down as intended.

However, the gesturerecognizer doesnt work properly. It detects touches to the small view containing the textfield, but not on the tableview.
I have tried adding the gesturerecognizer to the tableview, but it didnt seem to make a difference - the gestures weren't recognized. I also tried adding another view on top of the ContentView - it worked, but it didn't pass the events to the tableview below.

I have created the views with storyboard and added the code to move the views programatically.

Comment: Which gesture recognizer? It most likely conflicts with the ones that the table view has.

Comment: The tap recognizer does not work. How can I check whether it conflicts with the one from the table view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the answer provided [here]. I was not able to solve it with the storyboard gesture recognizer without additional code.[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20714873/592744)

Answer (score 0):

The gesture recognizer is working properly, make sure that it doesn't conflict with other event handlers. You can put break point into the method which is handling events to make sure it does really handles those events you wish. 
As the alternative, put a blank view in front of table view and attach gesture recognizer. :)

Comment: I tried the alternative, but I cannot pass all the other events such as swipe to the table view below. Also, break pointing shows that the tap gesture recognizer simply does not recognize a tap on the table view.